# angularjs localstorage displaying data

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs

i been tryi'n to use angular nowadays. i'm just hoping if someone could help me why i cant fetch localstorage data like the below codes. thanks

```
[
    {
    "name": "firstname",
    "email": "email@yahoo.com"
    }
]
```

service.js

```
 getItem: function (item) {

      var temp =  localStorage.getItem(item);

      if (!temp){
        return [];
      }

      return JSON.Parse(temp);

 }
```

controller.js

```
 profile.push({
                name: 'firstname',
                email: 'rmail@yahoo.com'
 });

localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify(profile));

 console.log(service.getItem('name') + ' : this should output the name');
 console.log(service.getItem('email') + ' : this should output the email');
```

Comment: where is  localstorage.setitem(key,value) called in ur code.??

Comment: i edited the codes. actually its working fines but right now its getting the json values raw = [{ "name": "firstname", "email":"email@yahoo.com"}] and my problem is how to get the value of name and email . thanks Neji

Comment: `var array = service.getItem('profiles')
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i].name, array[i].email)
}` Can you please try this.

Comment: @rajkamal it works! you nailed it man!

Comment: Fyi, AngularJS has `angular.toJson()` and `angular.fromJson()`. Just in case you're using < IE8 without json2/3.js

Comment: @koko, i will transfer my answer from comment section to answer section. Please mark it has correct, if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
var array = service.getItem('profiles');
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     console.log(array[i].name, array[i].email) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To forego using parsing and deal with any of this you can try a factory I recently created, it let's you store and retrieve arrays and objects. Also it let's you bind to $scope.variables:

https://github.com/agrublev/Angular-localStorage